# Model object is not matching with the database result

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

After the record iteration, the list key value is mismatching/wrongly shown ! what could be the reason.

Correct data in the database [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqNAl.png) is saved  (which is correct)

[Problem: You can see in this screenshot link, record is a mismatch with columns, e.g the key dayName has wrong value showing ,  key MenuIcon value is shown on dayName key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tfZf.png)

the sql lite DAO

```
    /*
* Get the all the exercises by ID asecending order
 */
public LinkedList<ExerciseDetails> getAllExerciseInfo() {
    LinkedList<ExerciseDetails> listCompanies = new LinkedList<ExerciseDetails>();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISE_DETAILS, mAllColumns,
            "",
            new String[]{}, "order_id", null, "order_id ASC");
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            ExerciseDetails company = cursorToExerciseDetails(cursor);
            listCompanies.add(company);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
    }
    return listCompanies;
}
```

### Full code of DAO for insertion,create table, list object . Please let me know any code you want to see, i will post

```
public class ExercisesDAO {

    public static final String TAG = "ExercisesDAO";

    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private DBHelper mDbHelper;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mAllColumns = {DBHelper.COLUMN_EX_DETAILS_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_ROUTINE_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_EXERCISE_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_REPS,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_SETS,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_TIME_PERSET,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_CALORIE_BURN,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_RESTTIME_PERSET,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_RESTTIME_POST_SET,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_ORDER_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_EXERCISE_NAME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_TIPS,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_YOUTUBE_URL,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_WARNINGS,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_DISPLAY_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISIBILITY,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_FOR_DATE,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_GIF,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_DAYNAME
    };

    public ExercisesDAO(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        // open the database
        try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SQLException on openning database " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public ExerciseDetails createExerciseDetail(String routineId,String dayId,
           String exerciseId, String reps,String sets, String timePerset,
           String calorieBurn, String resttimePerset, String resttimeAfterex,String order,
           String menuName, String tips, String youtubeUrl, String warnings, String displayId,
           String visibility, String forDate, String menuIcon, String dayName) {

        ExerciseDetails newCompany = null;
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ROUTINE_ID, routineId);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID, dayId);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_EXERCISE_ID, exerciseId);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_REPS, reps);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SETS, sets);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_TIME_PERSET, timePerset);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_CALORIE_BURN, calorieBurn);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RESTTIME_PERSET, resttimePerset);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RESTTIME_POST_SET, resttimeAfterex);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ORDER_ID, order);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_EXERCISE_NAME, menuName);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_TIPS, tips);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_YOUTUBE_URL, youtubeUrl);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_WARNINGS, warnings);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_DISPLAY_ID, displayId);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISIBILITY, visibility);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_FOR_DATE, forDate);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_GIF, menuIcon);
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_DAYNAME, dayName);

            long insertId = mDatabase
                    .insert(DBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISE_DETAILS, null, values);
            Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISE_DETAILS, mAllColumns,
                    DBHelper.COLUMN_EX_DETAILS_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null,
                    null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            newCompany = cursorToExerciseDetails(cursor);
            cursor.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", "exception in CreateFollowing class - " + e);
        }
        return newCompany;
    }


    public void executeSqlOnExerciseDetail(String sql) {
        mDatabase.execSQL(sql);
    }

    public Long getTotalCountExerciseDetail() {
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDatabase, DBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISE_DETAILS);
    }

    /*
    * Get the all the exercises by ID asecending order
     */
    public LinkedList<ExerciseDetails> getAllExerciseInfo() {
        LinkedList<ExerciseDetails> listCompanies = new LinkedList<ExerciseDetails>();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISE_DETAILS, mAllColumns,
                "",
                new String[]{}, "order_id", null, "order_id ASC");
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                ExerciseDetails company = cursorToExerciseDetails(cursor);
                listCompanies.add(company);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
        }
        return listCompanies;
    }


    /*
      * Check whether the exercise data present or not in the db before executing statement
     */
    public  boolean CheckIfRecordExists(String rid, String did) {

        String Query = "Select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISE_DETAILS + " where " + DBHelper.COLUMN_ROUTINE_ID + " = " + rid +  " AND " + DBHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID + " = " + did;
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }


    protected ExerciseDetails cursorToExerciseDetails(Cursor cursor) {
        try{
        ExerciseDetails exerciseDetails = new ExerciseDetails();

        exerciseDetails.setExDetailsId(cursor.getLong(0));
        exerciseDetails.setRoutineId(cursor.getString(1));
        exerciseDetails.setDayId(cursor.getString(2));
        exerciseDetails.setExerciseId(cursor.getString(3));
        exerciseDetails.setReps(cursor.getString(4));
        exerciseDetails.setSets(cursor.getString(5));
        exerciseDetails.setTimePerset(cursor.getString(6));
        exerciseDetails.setCalorieBurn(cursor.getString(7));
        exerciseDetails.setResttimePerset(cursor.getString(8));
        exerciseDetails.setOrder(cursor.getString(9));
        exerciseDetails.setMenuName(cursor.getString(10));
        exerciseDetails.setTips(cursor.getString(11));
        exerciseDetails.setYoutubeUrl(cursor.getString(12));
        exerciseDetails.setWarnings(cursor.getString(13));
        exerciseDetails.setDisplayId(cursor.getString(14));
        exerciseDetails.setVisibility(cursor.getString(15));
        exerciseDetails.setForDate(cursor.getString(16));
        exerciseDetails.setMenuIcon(cursor.getString(17));
        exerciseDetails.setDayName(cursor.getString(18));
        return exerciseDetails;

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("error------------"+e);
            return  null;
        }
    }

}
```

FUll json value which i inserted Into sqllite
https://pastebin.com/DmAkPkXg

Answer (score 0):

In `cursorToExerciseDetails()` instead of explicitly setting the index of a column:

```
exerciseDetails.setExDetailsId(cursor.getLong(0));
exerciseDetails.setRoutineId(cursor.getString(1));
....................................................
```

use `getColumnIndex()` with he name of the column to return the index:

```
exerciseDetails.setExDetailsId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_EX_DETAILS_ID)));
exerciseDetails.setRoutineId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ROUTINE_ID))));
....................................................
```